# How to create a category in Magento using SQL

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, sql

My attempts at creating a category with PHP fails while `flat_categories` are enabled in the system. Reference [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291197/delete-or-save-category-works-in-bootstrap-file-but-not-in-my-custom-api-control).

So, I want to create a new category in Magento 2 using SQL. How would I do that?

Comment: As Magento used **Eav structure** for categories. So using  a single SQL query category create not  possible

Comment: Yeah I know I can't be done with a single query. I am fine with multiple queries.